# How do I deploy tornado chatdemo.py (facebook) app on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, webserver, hosting, tornado

I just want to run the helloworld app given in Tornado - Facebook (chat demo) on Heroku.

How could I do that using Python?

I have simply tested a flask app on Heroku, but that procedure is not working for Tornado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out these resources?

- [How I Got a Tornado App Running on Heroku in 10 Seconds](http://log.liminastudio.com/programming/how-i-got-a-tornado-app-running-on-heroku-in-10-seconds)
- [Tornado Heroku helpers](https://github.com/virgildisgr4ce/Tornado-Heroku-Helpers)